# In Texmaker, how do I go to the source code that generates say, page 20?

Tags: texmaker

If I click a page number on the middle, it takes me to the output at that page, but what I really need is to go to the source code that generates that page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to Texmaker's manual:

> 3.3 Source-pdf synchronization with synctex
>
> By adding the option `-synctex=1` to the command for `pdflatex`, the integrated pdf display will position itself directly on the page corresponding to the current line in the editor. Conversely, with a `right-click` on a word in the integrated pdf display (contextual menu), the editor cursor will be positioned directly on the corresponding line in the source file. Note: if you press the `ctrl+space key`((`ctrl+$` on MacOsX) in the built-in pdf display, the editor returns to focus.